# Shorter Way To Write Expression Trees with Predicate Builder

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1, expression-trees, predicatebuilder

Is there an easier way to write the expression trees with Predicate Builder.  It just seems like a lot of code that can be condensed.

```
Expression<Func<EventGymCourt, object>> gymCourt = q => q.GymCourt;
Expression<Func<EventGymCourt, object>> gym = q => q.GymCourt.Gym;
Expression<Func<EventGymCourt, object>> address = q => q.GymCourt.Gym.Address;

_eventGymCourtRepository.GetWithStart(page, pageSize, new[] { gymCourt, gym, address }....
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to condense?

Comment: The expression tree initializations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I doubt that the types of the `GymCourt`, `Gym` and `Address` members are all `object`, so it's going to be difficult to get type-inference to work in your favour.

One way would be to use an array-initializer:

```
Expression<Func<EventGymCourt, object>>[] exprs 
      = { q => q.GymCourt, q => q.GymCourt.Gym, q => q.GymCourt.Gym.Address };

_eventGymCourtRepository.GetWithStart(page, pageSize, exprs);
```

If you really need  each expression in a separate variable, you can use a `using`-alias to shorten the variable type-declaration.

```
// At the top of your file....
using CourtObjectExpr = 
  System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<MyNameSpace.EventGymCourt, object>>;

...

CourtObjectExpr gymCourt = q => q.GymCourt;
CourtObjectExpr gym = q => q.GymCourt.Gym;
CourtObjectExpr address = q => q.GymCourt.Gym.Address;
```

---

By the way, you appear to be searching for the `Linq.Expr` method from [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) (the library that contains `PredicateBuilder`). This uses the compiler's type-inference features to condense the conversion of a lambda to an expression-tree in typical scenarios. I don't think this is all that useful in your example since you require the expression's return-type to be `object` rather than the property-type.

But *assuming* you want to create expressions with the property-type as the expression's return-type, you could have done (quite succinctly):

```
// Not directly applicable to your scenario (you can add a cast).
var gymCourt = Linq.Expr((EventGymCourt q) => q.GymCourt);
var gym =  Linq.Expr((EventGymCourt q) => q.GymCourt.Gym);
var address = Linq.Expr((EventGymCourt q) => q.GymCourt.Gym.Address);
```

This lets compiler type-inference work in your favour; the source-code for the method is as simple as:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, TResult>> Expr<T, TResult>
           (Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expr)
{
    return expr;
}
```

While that's not a direct fit for your situation, it's good to have in your toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

If You mean condensing initialization You can use var keyword for expression trees variables and write special extensions method ToExpression which simply returns given expression (but is needed by compiler to distinguish between func and expression).

Comment: Do you have an example?  I have done this with Expression<EventGymCourt>(true) to initialize it, but we still have three lines of code with .And.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [Mono.Linq.Expressions](http://evain.net/blog/articles/2012/01/11/mono-linq-expressions-update) by jb evain